# Getting SWI-Prolog to convert Literal to number

Tags: prolog, rdf, protege

It will be quite a miracle if someone could help with the following...

I'm using SWI-Prolog to perform queries in a triples RDF file. The values can be queried, but instead of just a number, the word Literal shows up in front of them (e.g [literal(500000)] shows up for the value 500000). Now, the problem arises when I have a list of numbers that I want to add. I try to convert these Literals into atoms so that Prolog can recognize them as numbers, but get the following error

ERROR: atom_number/2: Type error: atom' expected, found [literal(500000)]'

Any clues would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use unification to get the number. For instance

```
?- [literal(500000)] = [literal(N)].
N = 500000.
```